# Total noob. Need to emulate a keystroke using cmd or powershell script

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, powershell, script, macros

I am trying to emulate keystrokes in a specific application (dd.exe) ***in the background***. I have searched for answers, and found some snippets of script that give some information on how to do this, yet nothing clear enough that I have been able to figure out how to get it to work.

So far, I've tried using Pulover's Macro Creator to send keystrokes to this app, but it doesn't seem to work. So I figure there must be some other way I can run a script outside of the Macro Creator app that will simply emulate the keystrokes in the target application in the background (as if I'm actually hitting the keys on the keyboard with the application focused), while leaving me free to do my actual job work that I need to do in other apps while this script runs.

Reason being, I had a tragic data loss, and there are over 7,000 recovery files I need to use the down arrow key to navigate through, sample the header in a preview pane (using Macro Creator functionality), and depending on the contents of the preview sampling, either hit spacebar to mark the file, or just skip down to the next file.

So essentially, I think I will need to make 2 different scripts that I can run from Macro Creator: one to send the arrow down keystroke, and the other to send the spacebar.

Please let me know if this is possible, and assume that I am starting from scratch and don't even know how to save the script so that I can run it.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: This has the sound of a XY problem. Copy everything to another disk with a single run of your copying program of choice. Do the sorting out later. If you are copying from a bad disk the quicker you get what you can rescue of that disk the better. The disk will probably degrade further fast (Murphy's Law: It will go completely bad before you have copied everything) , so you don't have the time to spend on sorting while copying.

Comment: To add to Tonny's comment: Just running the computer with the disk powered on without disk access will wear the disk down if its a mechanical failure (bad sectors are a mechanical failure)

Comment: There is no mechanical failure issue. I simply had an installer run that uninstalled a preset folder that was a hard link, and thus it deleted every preset I had saved. I have everything found in this recovery app (Disk Drill), and am simply trying to automate sampling file preview data and selecting the files I need accordingly. Unfortunately, the app won't respond to input from MacroCreator - only when I physically click the mouse button or a key on my keyboard, hence the need to automate this process at a higher level in the OS.